# How do I store symmetric encryption keys securely?

Tags: c#, aes

I have some files which I want to encrypt (I think it will be AES). Each file should have a different key.

What is the best way to store the encryption key? I know it shouldn't be stored in the program itself, but should I store it in a file? Then I'm worried about the security of where the file is stored.

I know about CSP - but this way only for asymmetric keys (RSA). What about symmetric keys (AES)?

Comment: This is the most important part of security.  If you don't have a secure, separate place to store your key, encryption is useless.  Only you can answer this question, depending on who / what in your system can keep a secret.  Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: If the Windows user can keep a secret, you can use DPAPI instead.

Comment: The safety of the key is as safe as the hardware it's sitting on really. A safe(r) approach would be to offload the files to a secure server to deal with all the encryption/decryption that way the private key is never exposed. However, you then have the problem that you are sending *insecure* data across the wire once it's decrypted (although you could get around this by sending it across a secure channel).

Comment: SLaks, thanks a lot. I make decision to learn more about DPAPI and may be I just encrypt DB with keys on the files with one master key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about the encryption then the key is everything. eg key under the mat story. 
You can get a simple hardware device that can provide the key.  Someone would need physical access to the system to get the key.

[Hardware encryption key story](http://www.via.com.tw/en/initiatives/padlock/whyhardwareisbetter.jsp)

Ill let you research the HW tools on offer.  No plugs from me.

try [security stackechange.](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
The site is used by security experts.
Get a pro opinion...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I think that you can not rely on hardware as well as on the program modalities. After all the Trojan horse can capture key (key logging) information carriers and user it is sure that and this leads.

Comment: typically the devices have access control.   Suggest you take a second look before dismissing hardware. See edit for new link